# Work while app is suspended in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I want to know what, how, and the limitations of the work that can be done whilst an app is suspended.
I'm not talking about `Background Tasks`, since those run whether the app is suspended or not, but what you can do while the app is in the background, suspended.

What I noticed so far is that if I have a `BackgroundTask` with the `Completed` event attached in the MainApp, that trigger is fired whilst the app is suspended, meaning that I can in fact do work in the MainApp, with the app suspended. So far I only have two ways of doing that, one is by using a `BackgroundTask` `Completed` event, and the other is by having a timer that forces something to happen.

However, what, how and the limitations of what I can do with the suspended app are not clear to me.

So, is there another way of working with a suspended app? And how much CPU time do I have, if limited, to work with?

Comment: How did you find out that the `Completed` event handler has been executed? When the debugger is attached, the app is not really suspended, but you can simulate it using the `Debug Location` toolbar Lifecycle events.

Comment: I did it in two ways, with the Lyfecycle events and detached from the VS like a normal app. To check if it was executing I wrote logs to a file and it worked.

Comment: As I've tested your sample it turns out that you are right. Though, I don't why this happens - if it's desired behavior or not.

Comment: I was faced with a situation where I needed to do background work whilst the app suspended and came across that. I do think that you should be able to take advantage of the suspended app and not with BG tasks, since those do not need the app at all as they're handled by the system. Maybe in W10 mobile this will change.

Comment: @ricochete I guess you are right and we have to wait for W10. I also won't relay on this behavior and as Kristian Vukusic has said, there will be problem when the app gets terminated.

Answer (score 1):

I have played around a bit and found out that `MessageWebSocket`, if not disposed on app suspension, can still receive messages.

You could use the open socket connection to send messages, based on which you can execute code in the background.

A problem is when your app gets terminated by the OS (when the device does not have enough memory), then the socket connection will be closed too.

For more info on how to implement sockets see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh452976.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion. I'm concluding that if an app lets some attached event open, you can still trigger it from an outside source like a BG task or a WebSocket like you said. Still the MS doc isn't clear on this and I suppose you'll be able to do work until the OS decides to kill your app, probably due to the memory consumption.

Answer (score 0):

You should check this link.

[Understanding the App’s Lifecycle and Managing State - By Bob Tabor](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-1-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Part-12-Understanding-the-App-s-Lifecycle-and-Managing-State)

Here its shown how you can manage to save the state of the app if your app is being suspended using suspension manager and also how to save data if the app is terminated from the suspension state.

Bob Tabor has clearly explained this in detail.

It was helpful to me, hope this helps you.